# Upgrading from ubuntu 12.04 LTS to lubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and would like to upgrade to Lubuntu 14.04 LTS. A person I know has a Lubuntu 14.04 DVD.

Can I upgrade core system/libraries using that then upgrade rest of the packages via Internet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it is wise to try to update Ubuntu using Lubuntu media, despite them being almost the same, I would suggest doing the distro upgrade via

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Or via the graphical Software Updater (which I believe in this case would just be a front-end).

Comment: This is good advice. If you don't want to do an online upgrade, or want to have a cleaner system (without all the software and configs you have added to 12.04) then find a person with the Ubuntu 14.04 DVD. Make sure the version is 32 or 64 bit the same as your current install. that is, if you have a 32 bit install, then the 64 bit DVD won't work and vice versa. Then upgrade from the DVD.